# How to reduce sample rate using integer division?

Tags: c, signals, signal-processing, frequency

I want to reduce my base frequency F (80000 Hz) by an **arbitrary fraction using only integer devision**.

Let's say that new_sample() function is called with a frequency F. Then I can reduce sample rate to 40000 Hz using code below.

```
i = 0; // global counter
new_sample(value){
    if(i % 2 == 0){
        add_sample_to_buffer(value);
    }else{
        // skip sample
    }
    i++;
}
```

What if I want to reduce sample rate by a factor of 1.6 to 50000 Hz?

As Clifford pointed out: I want to change sample rate without changing the frequency.  Basically I want to undersample the signal by skipping some samples in real time.

p.s.:
I know that prescaler and postcaler are usualy used to reduce frequiency. I dont know if they allow to reduce frequency by a fraction.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking.  If you know the exact frequency of the signal you want, you do not need to modify the frequency of some other signal - you can simply generate that frequency directly.  I suspect what you are trying to do and what you are describing are not in fact the same thing.  Are you rather wanting to change the _sample_rate_ without changing the frequency perhaps?

Comment: By skipping every other sample you will _double_ the frequency when replayed at the same sample rate.  It looks like you are in fact intending to reduce the _sample rate_ without changing the _frequency_ of the signal.  Is that the case?

Comment: @Clifford yes. I want to change the sample rate without changing the frequency. Basicaly I want to undersample the signal by skipping some samples.

Comment: Then you should edit the question to make that clear because it does not currently say that.  Meanwhile the answer is [resampling](https://dspguru.com/dsp/faqs/multirate/resampling/).

Comment: You are also asking an X-Y question - asking how to reduce the sample rate _using integer division_ is unnecessarily constraining possible answers.  What you want to know is how to reduce the sample rate - integer division is irrelevant.  A solution using integer arithmetic is perhaps a fair constraint.  The FIR filter you need requires multiplication and addition - no division necessary.

Comment: @Clifford integer division is highly relevant. Any floating point operations are too slow to run on microcontroller that I am useing.

Comment: You can't without trying to reconstruct a signal resample it. If your sampling frequency is 40kHz, then you can under-sample integer fraction of it, half, 20kHz, one third 13kHz, etc. just removing one sample over two or two over three, etc. But you can't easily have factor 1.6. Or by having a variable sampling frequency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
unsigned Nanoseconds = 0; // global counter

void new_sample(value){
    Nanoseconds += 12500; // interval between calls at 80000 
    if(Nanoseconds>20000){
        Nanoseconds-=20000;
        add_sample_to_buffer(value);
    }else{
        // skip sample
    }
}
```

During one second `Nanoseconds` will be incremented 80000 times by 12500 which is equal 1E9, and will be 50000 times decremented by 20000.

Comment: Some discussion of how the irregular sampling affects the signal or how one might adjust by *resampling* would be good.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: There are already comments present regarding over/undersampling etc. under the OP. Yes, I think if my code is used to downscale an image it will create artefacts due to the repeatedly applied  discard pattern.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the sample rate of the signal, without changing the absolute position of the signal content, you want to do what is in signal processing known as "decimation". If you want to learn about it, you may wish to read this very dense university lecture: https://homepages.wmich.edu/~bazuinb/ECE6560/CR_DecAndInterp.pdf. In a nutshell, you have to perform some filtering, some decimation, as well as some interpolation. More simple explanation is here: https://dspguru.com/dsp/faqs/multirate/decimation/, and it does have a link towards the scopeFIR free tool that includes decimation phase filters, together with the source code. A lot of reading, I know...